# how to fix a random choice generator?

Tags: python

My python game isn't working, the sequences beginning with:

```
if int(total_time) > 10:
```

isn't triggering, but when I press D, C  or W I am getting the 'you opened something' text though. The code there is right as far as I know, it's just not working. I used the or prevtime to allow you to do it the first time.

```
import random, time, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
total_time = time.clock()
pygame.init()
XQR_prevtime = 0
ppayh_prevtime = 0
pu_ekaw_prevtime = 0
diff = 1
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
time.sleep(3)
XQR_awakened = False
ppayh_awakened = False
pu_ekaw_awakened = False

    if int(total_time) > 10:

        if int(XQR_prevtime) > (12 - diff) or int(XQR_prevtime) == 0 or XQR_awakened == True:
            if XQR_awakened == True:
                print("You left something open...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("And a mystery came in")
                time.sleep(2)
                sys.exit()
            if random.randint(0,diff) == 1:
                print(3)
                XQR_prevtime = time.clock()
                door_opening.play()
                XQR_awakened = True

        if int(ppayh_prevtime) > (12 - diff) or int(ppayh_prevtime) == 0 or ppayh_awakened == True:
            if ppayh_awakened == True:
                print("You left something open...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("And a friend came in")
                time.sleep(2)
                sys.exit()
            if randint(0,diff) == 1:
                print(3)
                ppayh_prevtime = time.clock()
                closet_opening.play()
                ppayh_awakened = True

        if int(pu_ekaw_prevtime) > (12 - diff) or int(pu_ekaw_prevtime) == 0 or pu_ekaw_prevtime == True:
            if ekaw_up_awakened == True:
                print("You left something open...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("And an answer came in")
                time.sleep(2)
                sys.exit()
            if randint(0,diff) == 1:
                print(3)
                pu_ekaw_prevtime = time.clock()
                window_opening.play()
                pu_ekaw_awakened = True
```

Comment: You never update `total_time`. You need to call `time.clock()` **each time through the loop**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total_time` *never changes*, so you can never reach your condition.

The line

```
total_time = time.clock()
```

assigns a numeric value (a `float`) to `total_time`. There is no reference back to the `time.clock()` function, the function returns *just a normal float object*, not a timer object.

And normal `float` values don't change, they are immutable. The `total_time` value is not going to change as you game runs.

If you want to measure elapsed time, just keep calling `time.clock()`:

```
if time.clock() > 10:
```

You don't need to convert a float value to `int` here, comparisons with integers just work.